# boxplot: index out of range error

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to plot a big number of boxplots in one figure. I succeed to show 9 boxplots and i want to get more boxplots. i used the following code.
to get the data from csv file:

```
a = getData("/home/abuabderrahmen/caidama.csv")
a1 = a.ix[0:,['Conductance']]
```

The same process allows to get an arbitrary number of arrays. then i create my frame objects using:

```
e1 = concatenate( (a1, b1, c1), 0 )
data1 = [e1, e1, e1[::3,0]]
```

Finally i plot the boxes using

```
bp = boxplot(data1, positions = [1.05, 1.35, 1.65], widths = 0.15)
```

To get 12 boxplots, i make the following changes:

```
e1 = concatenate( (a1, b1, c1, d1), 0 )
data1 = [e1, e1, e1[::4,0]]
bp = boxplot(data1, positions = [1.05, 1.35, 1.65, 1.95], widths = 0.15)
```

and I get a list index out of range error.
What is going wrong in this approach?

Comment: Show us the error message.

Comment: `.ix` Is deprecated in pandas 0.20

Answer (score 0):

It appears the only case you may have `IndexError` is in `boxplot`, when you try to plot an array whose length is not equal to that of your `positions` array. i.e.:

```
>>> plt.boxplot([1,2,3], positions=[1.05, 1.35, 1.65, 1.95], widths = 0.15)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#66>", line 1, in <module>
    plt.boxplot([1,2,3], positions=[1.05, 1.35, 1.65, 1.95], widths = 0.15)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib    /pyplot.py", line 2442, in boxplot
    usermedians=usermedians, conf_intervals=conf_intervals)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 5815, in boxplot
    d = np.ravel(x[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I suspect your `e1[::4,0]` is not long enough.